# PHP string on Host server from DW CS6

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, dreamweaver

I am new to PHP and teaching myself. I have built some training sites but I am having a problem when I load the files from Dreamweaver 6 to my internet hosting server. 
The site works and displays fine locally. But when I load the site files on the hosting server and try to view the site it gives me an error coming from my server strings. If I edit the code on the server file(see below) I can make it work fine.

Is there a setting on DW that I need to do to make it compatible and not have to be edited once I put the files to the host server? Or is it a version problem? I am using DW CS6 and PHP version 5.4.3
My hosting server is using PHP 5.3.

Here what the code looks like....

Existing code that comes from Dreamweaver - "mysql_select_db($database_ique22, $ique22)";

On server if I edit to the following it clears the error - "mysql_select_db($database_ique22)";

Thanks for any advice.....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with what Dreamweaver implements as far as helping with PHP, but if you're really interested in learning PHP I'd ditch Dreamweaver altogether. The PHP.net docs are fantastic and an editor like Sublime Text 2 will work much better for you without doing confusing things.

In any case, the second parameter of `mysql_select_db` is the link identifier (used generally if you need to connect to multiple MySQL servers). It should only throw an error if `$ique22` is not set to a MySQL connection using something along the lines of `$ique22 = mysql_connect("server","user","pass");`

One thing to keep in mind is that the mysql_ function set is deprecated and you'll want to switch to using mysqli.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php